# What are other alternatives to using e.Cancel = true in Validating event?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, user-interface

I have some login-type form wherein I do validation on a number of textboxes.

Here's the validation code for a `Textbox`:

```
private void Required_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // clear errors set by provider
    this.errorProvider1.SetError((Control)sender, null);
}

private void Required_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
    {
        // required field is filled up
        return;
    }

    e.Cancel = true;
    // show to user an error message
    this.errorProvider1.SetError(control, Resources.RequiredFieldPopup);
}
```

Based on the end-user requirement, they don't like the behavior produced by `e.Cancel = true` in `TextBox.Validating` event -- setting it to true forces the user to enter a valid input, and **you can't go to any other control until you've fixed your input**.

What would be an ideal alternative/design revision to this common validation design wherein `Validated` and `Validating` events are both put to use as its intended design?

Comment: `e.Cancel` is an optional choice. You can just set the Error for the control, to show a hint that something's wrong. In the end, before doing what this UI is supposed to do, check `ErrorProvider.GetError()` (or an *error counter* value), notify and don't proceed further until all errors are fixed. It will allow users to modify the input before submitting it without being *locked* inside a control.

Comment: @Jimi I can't just remove `e.Cancel` assignment since the system flow would be: fires `Validating` event, error provider sets error, and then `Validated` event will fire, then remove the error just set in `Validating` event. This way, it seems like I would have no need for **both** events, and do my validation logic on either one of them. Btw, I already tried this but I think it breaks the purpose of the partner events `Validated` and `Validating`.

Comment: In the `Validated` event, you can remove the ErrorProvider hint only in case `GetError()` returns empty. It's your choice how you handle these events. This is more or less what `EnableAllowFocusChange` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you submit the form fields to the Database or Active Directory for authentication using a button click, why not validate the fields there, eg:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  bool isValid = true;
  foreach( var control in this.Controls)
   {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text)) 
      { 
          isValid = false;
          this.errorProvider1.SetError(control, Resources.RequiredFieldPopup);
      }
   }
   if (!isValid) return;
  }
```

Another way is to use the LostFocus TextBox event.

*PS: Typed on my phone*

Comment: This is really one way to do it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could unsubscribe and re-subscribe Events `+=` and `-=` I guess, but this is heaps cleaner. It's also standard UX/UI design to validate on submit (unless there is client-side JavaScript - I know this is Winforms and hence the `LostFocus` event), that's what the end-users really have a problem with. Ps If you accept you'll get the 2 pts rep to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found a solution that's the ideal scenario for the end users. It's `Form.AutoValidate` property, set to **`EnableAllowFocusChange`**. I also think *this* should be the default value of this property. I have been on developing using WinForms for many years now and I only found out about this now (guess I wasn't Googling enough).

For a more visual explanation on the difference of the behavior, refer to [this](https://blog.gfader.com/2008/12/winforms-ui-best-practices.html?m=0).